# adding modules to installed asterisk - alsa.so not found

Tags: centos, asterisk

I have set

```
load= chan_alsa.so
```

and i got this error

```
ERROR[77064] loader.c: Error loading module 'alsa.so': /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/alsa.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

is there a missing module or `alsa` is global ?

Comment: Try running `sudo yum install alsa-lib-devel` and see if that does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Probably yo have not installed the asterisk-alsa package. Please try

```
yum install asterisk-alsa
```